# Does it matter which algorithm you use for Multiple Imputation by Chained Equations (MICE)

Tags: imputation, r-mice

I have seen MICE implemented with different types of algorithms e.g. RandomForest or Stochastic Regression etc.

My question is that does it matter which type of algorithm i.e. does one perform the best? Is there any empirical evidence?
I am struggling to find any info on the web

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, (depending on your task) it can matter quite a lot, which algorithm you choose.

You also can be sure, the `mice` developers wouldn't out effort into providing different algorithms, if there was one algorithm that anyway always performs best. Because, of course like in machine learning the "No free lunch theorem" is also relevant for imputation.

In general you can say, that the default settings of **mice** are often a good choice.

Look at this [example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miceRanger/vignettes/miceAlgorithm.html) from the miceRanger Vignette to see, how far imputations can differ for different algorithms. (the real distribution is marked in red, the respective multiple imputations in black)

[image]

The Predictive Mean Matching (pmm) algorithm e.g. makes sure that only imputed values appear, that were really in the dataset. This is for example useful, where only integer values like 0,1,2,3 appear in the data (and no values in between). Other algorithms won't do this, so while doing their regression they will also provide interpolated values like on the picture to the right ( so they will provide imputations that are e.g. 1.1, 1.3, ...) Both solutions can come with certain drawbacks.
That is why it is important to actually assess imputation performance afterwards. There are several diagnostic plots in mice to do this.